# Displaying Gridview and then later loading?

Tags: android, gridview, lazy-loading

I am using `GridView` to display more than 100 images from web. Its takes time to load and display, so I use lazy loading but that does not speed it up.

So I want to display the view or activity first and then I want to display the images in the background.

How do I achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Fedor's Lazy Loading logic: [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

Yes this answer is for Loading images inside the ListView, but you can use the same for GridView as well. I had implemented previously and it was working fine in my case.

Comment: Thank you ,but i am using same lazy laoding class,but still its taking time ,thats reason i want to display the layout first and displaying lazy laoding if u have any idea plz.......help me.....